# git for-each-ref equivalent in GitPython?

Tags: gitpython

I would like to iterate over all the references using the GitPython API, in the same way git for-each-ref does it. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

On a repository created with

```
import git
r = git.Repo('.')
```

the `r.refs` data member is a list of all the references, as it would be returned by `git for-each-ref` (see http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.refs for more information).